# No entiendo como en este bucle for se saca pares de un array y los agrupa en otro array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando comprender este código en el bucle for, no entiendo que se intenta hacer con j+1, como es que logra sacar pares del array tandem? agradecería mucho si alguien puede ver lo que hace y me lo explicase.
La finalidad de ese codigo es sacar pares de ese array y a agruparlos en otro array llamado teams:

```
tandem= [ 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 7, 9, 1 ]

for (let j = 0; j < tandem.length; j+1) {
        console.log(j);
        teams.push(tandem.splice(j, 2));
    }
    console.log(teams)
```

**Al imprimir el array teams está es la salida:**

```
[ [ 5, 3 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 3, 7 ], [ 9, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: Aparte de la explicación que pides... ¿el código hace lo que se pretende que haga?  Si lo ejecuto en jsfiddle me da [otro resultado](https://jsfiddle.net/p7hLgyxd/). ¿Cuando dices pares te refieres a arreglos/arrays de dos elementos o a números pares?  Aclara esos puntos para poderte responder correctamente, pues el planteamiento que expones no me parece nada claro porque el resultado que tu tienes es otro.

Comment: Que pena el array tándem tiene valores incorrectos, ya lo modifique. Respondiendote, sip debo almacenar en un array vacío (llamado teams), pares para que quede de está forma: [ [ 5, 3 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 3, 7 ], [ 9, 1 ] ], es decir del array tandem saco lo pares para meterlos en el array teams. Entonces mi duda está en que no se como entender el condicional for cuando se incrementa y como logra sacar los pares con el metodo splice()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio **teams** no existe fuera del for, por lo que para hacerlo funcionar quizás exista un array **teams** también declarado antes del for.

Dicho esto lo que está sucediendo es que **j** nunca está aumentando, una solución a eso podría ser reemplazar el **j+1** por **j++** o **j+=1** (ambos son equivalentes de **j = j+1**)

Entonces, en cada iteración del for mientras **j** sea menor que el length de **tandem** hace un push en **teams** de lo que devuelve el splice, que son los 2 elementos eliminados de **tandem** empezando desde la posición cero siempre.

Entonces:
Caso 1
j = 0
tandem= [ 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 7, 9, 1 ]
teams = [[5,3]]

Caso 2
j = 0
tandem= [ 5, 6, 3, 7, 9, 1 ]
teams = [[5,3],[5,6]]

Caso 3
j = 0
tandem= [ 9, 1 ]
teams = [[5,3],[5,6],[3, 7]]

Caso 4
j = 0
tandem= []
teams = [[5,3],[5,6],[3, 7], [9, 1]]

En este punto **j** deja de ser menor que el **length de tandem**, sale del for y hace el console.log de **teams** que imprime:
[[5,3],[5,6],[3, 7], [9, 1]]

Si se modifica el valor de **j** cambiandolo por **j++** o **j+=1** en cada iteración arrancará del indice que corresponde al valor de **j**, lo cual devolverá un resultado diferente.

Comment: Luis, muchas gracias, pude ver otra perspectiva adicional con tu explicación que me ayudaron entender el código

Comment: Me alegra mucho, siempre es un placer. Quedo al las órdenes.

Answer (score 5):

Vale, vamos a ver si consigo que lo entiendas.

### Paso a paso:

1. Esto parece un bucle normal, pero no lo és. Han cambiado el típico **j++** (que incrementaria la **`j`** en uno en cada ciclo) por algo totalmente aleatorio, en este caso `j+1`, para que no afecte al valor de la **`j`**, la cual pretenden dejar intacta en todos los ciclos, es decir, con valor **0**:

```
for (let j = 0; j < tandem.length; j+1) {
```

Date cuenta que si pones cualquier otra cosa en lugar de `j+1`, que no afecte al valor del **`j`**, funciona igual.

2. Te preguntarás... ***¿entonces es un bucle infinito?***  Pues no, porque en lugar de modificar el valor de la **`j`** lo que hacen es modificar la longitud de la variable **`tandem`** (*tandem.length*) haciendo esto:

```
teams.push(tandem.splice(j, 2));
```

que dicha instrucción, aparte de incrementar la variable **teams** en un elemento, gracias al método [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), **sustrae/elimina** del array **`tandem`** desde el elemento con índice **j** (es decir, 0) un total de **2** elementos, gracias al método **splice()**.

Si mirás la documentación de [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) verás que dice lo siguiente:

> El método splice() cambia el contenido de un array eliminando
> elementos existentes y/o agregando nuevos elementos.

De ahí que esté agregando un nuevo elemento de array compuesto de dos elementos en cada ciclo (gracias a **push*), que van coincidiendo con los dos primeros que se va encontrando en cada ciclo dentro de la variable **tandem** (gracias a **splice(0,2)**), una vez eliminados los anteriores.

Date cuenta de nuevo que si cambias la **j** por **0** te funciona también igual.

El bucle termina cuando la **j**, que vale **0** siempre, deja de ser menor que la longitud del array **tandem** `0 < tandem.length`, y como en cada ciclo le quitamos dos elementos, llega un punto en que la longitud de **tandem** es **0** también y el bucle termina.

Aquí dejo un snippet para que lo ejecutes, con el cambio de `j+1` por cualquier otra cosa, y cambiando la **j** por **0** en el **splice** para que veas que sigue funcionando, y donde también inicializo la variable de array **teams**, tal como ya hice en [el enlace](https://jsfiddle.net/p7hLgyxd/) que te puse en los comentarios.

```js
tandem= [ 5, 3, 5, 6, 3, 7, 9, 1 ]
teams = []
for (let j = 0; j < tandem.length; j+33) {
  console.log(j);
  teams.push(tandem.splice(0, 2));
}
console.log(teams)
```

Comment: GENIO!, mi pregunta ahora es, entonces cual sería la finalidad de ese bucle for, talvez es porque cada vez que se le quita dos elementos al array tandem la variable J siempre empezará desde 0?, veo que también puedo usar for (const index in tandem), entonces esto me lleva a esa conclusión, osea que la J o lo que sería el index siempre empezará en 0 debido a que splice() elimina de 2 elementos seteando los indices del array tandem desde cero hasta dejarlo vacio

Comment: La finalidad del bucle, por lo que yo entiendo, es llegar al punto de `0<0` y como eso no es cierto entonces termina el bucle. En mi última actualización de la respuesta lo explico en el párrafo que empieza por `El bucle termina cuando la j,`.  Entiendo que ese código no es tuyo, por lo tanto me he limitado a explicar lo que he visto. Evidentemente habrá otras soluciones, pero eso no era lo que preguntabas :-)

Comment: En cuanto al `for...in` cuidado, porque según veo si lo usas en un array puede darte problemas si lo usas pensando que va a respetar el orden de sus indices. Léete bien su [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#iteraci%C3%B3n_en_arreglos_y_for...in) donde habla del uso de arreglos (arrays) con el.

Comment: @HugoBustamante `for (let j = 0; j < tandem.length; j+1)` podrías bien cambiarlo por `for (let j = 0; j < tandem.length; )` ya que la última operación sólo es un desperdicio de recursos

Comment: Brother de verdad que te agradezco mucho, con tu explicación entendí perfectamente ese código, gracias